# Spatial functions and Google Maps

Tags: mysql, sql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis

I have a Google Map where I'd like to display some markers etc.

If you open the website, it sets session to "geometrycollection empty". When the map is fully loaded, it makes an AJAX request with NE & SW lat and lng as parameters.

Handle method for AJAX looks like that:

```
$contain = $this->locationsManager->getContainOfAreas($this->getSession("union")->area, $polygon);


$area = $this->locationsManager->getDifferentiatedArea($polygon, $this->getSession("union")->area);
$coordinates = $this->locationsManager->getLocationsCoordinates($area["polygon"]);
$this->getSession("union")->area = $this->locationsManager->getUnionOfAreas($this->getSession("union")->area, $area["polygon"])["unionArea"];
```

But when I try to find out if area B (*$this->getSession("union")->area* - union of areas (viewports) user "visited") contains area A (*$polygon* - current viewport in Google Maps), it returns wrong results (I drew polygons from the variables via Google Maps Polygons and they were different).

This is SQL command for getting result of getContainOfAreas:

```
SELECT ST_CONTAINS(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(?), ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(?)) AS result;
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post a picture with the obtained and the desired results?

Comment: @antonio Thanks, Antonio. But I finally figured out what was the problem (wrong AJAX requests, it means it was my failure and values returned from database were right).